# React Router: define routes using PlainRoute

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Example I define my application's route using `React Router`'s `PlainRoute`

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ({
  path        : '/',
  component   : CoreLayout,
  indexRoute  : Home,
  childRoutes : [
    CounterRoute(store),
  ]
});
```

`CoreLayout` as a base style (Header, Footer, ...) for my whole application:

```
export const CoreLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <div className='container text-center'>
    <Header />
    <div className='core-layout__viewport'>
      {children}
    </div>
  </div>
);
export default CoreLayout;
```

My question is: How can I define routes so that:

1. Route A doesn't use CoreLayout. (this case, route A is login screen).
2. Route B, Route C ... always nested inside CoreLayout.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to render some components inside another component e.g. in your `CoreLayout` with react-router just make them child routes of route which points to your `CoreLayout`. Other components which are not in child routes of your `CoreLayout` won't be rendered inside it. Then in your `createRoutes` function return array of routes. Here is possible solution for you.

```
export const createRoutes = (store) => ([
  {
    path: '/',
    component: CoreLayout,
    indexRoute: Home,
    childRoutes: [
        CounterRoute(store),
    ]
  },
  {
     path: '/login',
     component: YourLoginComponent
  }
]);
```